Issue configuring ACLs for Apache Kafka on a Kraft broker
Running kafka_2.13-3.7.0 on RHES 8.9, I created a three broker Kraft cluster. In each of the server property files for the brokers, I added the following and restarted.
authorizer.class.name=org.apache.kafka.metadata.authorizer.StandardAuthorizer
allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=true
I now see the serializer failed to start and the broker crashes.
Any idea what I am doing wrong?
I am under the presumption that I do not need SASL for basic user matching.
I just want to only permit based on the incoming uid.
No SSL has been configured yet.
